# Shapefile layer not showing on QGIS v3.16 and above

Tags: qgis

I have come across an issue which seems to be QGIS version related.

A vector layer was created in QGIS v3.14 and it displays fine. However, when opening the project in v3.16.8 or v3.20 the layer does not display (see first image below).  The data does show when I view the attribute table in v3.16.8.

The layer does display if I open the project in v3.12 (see second image below).

Even if the layer style is saved in v3.14 and I apply the style when I have the project open in v3.16 it does not show.

[image: Snapshot from QGIS v3.20]

[image: Snapshot from QGIS v3.12]

Comment: What happens if you do a right click on the layer / `zoom to layer`? Maybe this layer does not have a projection and the project CRS is different in both versions?

Comment: "zoom to layer" zooms to the correct (same) extent in all versions. The layer CRS is set so unfortunately that is not it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely related to an issue with QGIS v3.16 and v3.18. The layers show normally on v3.22.5 and above.